# API Errors on Azure while creating a Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to create a workflow on Azure whereby I receive an email from a certain email address (trigger), and a Document Library is modified off the back of this (Action). I have the Office 365 Connector working, but when I try to Authorize the Sharepoint connector, I get an error that reads:

"Error fetching API Definition. Code: Undefined, Message: Undefined"

Does anyone know why I'm getting this error? Is it something to do with how I set up the connector? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the documentation for Sharepoint - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-logic-connector-sharepoint/

There were a few bugs in the sharepoint connector that have been since fixed. Please do let us know if you still are hitting this. At that point, please share the config details of the connector as well.